# ACLS not recognized

Tags: strongloop, loopbackjs

I'm following the sample app style of defining a json file in the models directory, along with a .js file to load the json.

My problem is that the acls definitions in my json file, which denies the `everyone` role, is not being recognized. I am able to `GET` `api/clients` as a non-privileged user successfully with a status `200`. I expect to get a status `401`, access denied.

As a test, I add the same acls definitions to the json of the default user model, and I get a status `401` access denied as expected.

Here is some of `client.json` (as in a customer, not to be confused with front-end stuff)

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "public": true,
  "dataSource": "db",
  "plural": "clients",
  "options": {
    "strict": true,
    "acls": [
      {
        "accessType": "*",
        "permission": "DENY",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$everyone"
      }
    ],
    "scopes": {
      "active": {"where": {"active": true}, "order": "company_name"}
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "generated": true,
      "id": true
    },
    "active": {
      "type": "Boolean",
      "default": true
    },
    "company_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "length": 64
    }
}
```

client.js

```
var app = require('./../app');
var db = app.dataSources.db;

// Load config
var config = require('./client.json');

// Create model from config
var Client = db.createModel('client', config);

// Add to REST API
app.model(Client);

module.exports = Client;
```

Should acls be working on my client model or is there something else I need to setup here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

`config.properties` and `config.options` should be sent into `createModel` as separate arguments.

```
var Client = db.createModel('client', config.properties, config.options);
```

No errors will be generated if you pass in the entire config as properties.

Also note that `config.plural` also works when defined inside the `config.options` object.